# Reading a text file in blocks - losing data?

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a huge text file that can be anywhere from 2 to 20 GBs. The content is a list of results from a given list of queries. I am trying to send it into my 'parse' script in blocks, as I need each set of results to be read into memory so that I can do index operations on them. For some reason, when I load the entire file into memory, I get more parsing results than if I use the following code to chop my input file into blocks:

```
with open(infile, 'r') as rfile:
    block = []
    thresh = 100000
    for i, line in enumerate(rfile):

        if i >= thresh:
            if "Iteration: 1" in line: # This marks the end of one set of results, and the beginning of the next, so we don't truncate any results
                read_block(block)
                thresh += 100000
                del block[:]

        block.append(line)
```

Any idea why I am losing data with this code? Or is everything kosher here, and my error is the result of this function interacting weirdly with the read_block() method...

Comment: What's the threshold for, if you're willing to blow past it to reach the end of a result set?  Why not just read and process one result set at a time instead of some magic number of lines?

Comment: Also, what happens to the last results set(s)?  I don't see a final call to `read_block` to process whatever ends up in the last `block`.

Answer (score 0):

This nested `if` is probably causing you problems (possibly with help from `read_block`):

```
if i >= thresh:
    if "Iteration: 1" in line:
        read_block(block)
        thresh += 100000
        del block[:]
```

It is equivalent to a compound `if` condition, since it only runs the innermost block if *both* conditions are true:

```
if i >= thresh and "Iteration: 1" in line:
    read_block(block)
    thresh += 100000
    del block[:]
```

So whenever this loop encounters a short set of results --- less than 100,000 lines ---  the outer `for` loop continues slurping in results sets until their *combined* length passes the threshold.  When `read_block` is finally called, it will be given a `block` of lines that contains two or more sets.  Can `read_block` cope with that?

Also, if you have a particularly long results set --- or any combination of sets that don't add up to exactly 100,000 lines --- the threshold is completely ignored until the loop reaches the end of the current set.  If your other functions assume that `block` can never exceed 100,000 lines, they will get a rude surprise.

Finally, `thresh` is always incremented by 100,000, instead of however many lines were actually read.  Since this can't happen until `i >= thresh` (possibly *much* greater-than), `thresh` will lag farther and farther behind reality.  If that 100,000-line threshold really is important, you should set it to 100,000 lines *from now*:

```
thresh = i + 100000
```

To reiterate what I commented above, why not just feed `read_block` (or `read_one_results_set` or whatever) a single results set at a time, and not worry about counting lines?